# $R/I$ is commutative iff $rs-sr \in I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to go with proving this :
Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be an Ideal of $R$.

Prove that the factor ring $R/I$ is commutative iff $rs-sr \in I$ $\forall r$ and $s$ in $R$

any hint how to go with this...

Comment: There are some problems with the question - firstly, the statement "$rs-sr$ is commutative for all $r,s\in R$" doesn't appear to depend on $I$, whereas the statement "$R/I$ is commutative" clearly does. Maybe one of $r$ or $s$ should be in $I$? Secondly, I don't know what you mean by "$rs-sr$ is commutative"; maybe that it is central (i.e. that $t(rs-sr)=(rs-sr)t$ for all $t$)? Or that it is zero?

Comment: Well, for $R/I$ to be commutative, all commutators must be sent to $0$, so we need all commutators to be in $I$.

Comment: @MattPressland I've made edit .$rs-sr \in I$ .that was error with my writing the statement also your second doubt ,it was miswritten by me "rs−sr is commutative"; ...Sorry for that....

Comment: @spectraa This boils down to $rs + I = sr + I \iff rs - sr \in I$.

Comment: @spectraa Ok, that's better - now the other comments point out that this is essentially tautological.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $R/I$ is commutative, then $(r+I)(s+I)=(s+I)(r+I) \implies (rs+I)=(sr+I) \implies rs-sr \in I$.

Conversely, let for any $r,s \in R$,  $rs-sr \in I$ then reversing the above implications, you will get it.

Answer (score 2):

You should really look at the definition of a quotient again! (you will see the result immediately)

Basically you have equivalence classes $[x] \in R/I$ which are zero precisely when one (or every) representative $x \in [x]$ lies in $I$. Hence your statement follows then easy by:

$$
[rs]=[r][s]=[s][r]=[sr]
$$